# Modifying CSV content with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file, **Devices.csv**, containing  **IP Address, DeviceName, SerialNumber, MAC Address, UserName**.

The **Users** column in all the rows of **Devices.csv** is prepopulated with a value [Unknown]

The code...

```
{Import-CSV Devices.csv | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -eq '192.168.2.124'} | Select-Object -last 1 | FT  IPAddress, devicveName, SerialNumber,  MACAddress, User -AutoSize }
```

....outputs

```
IPAddress     deviceName     SNumber     MACAddress   User
---------     -----          -------     ----------   ----
192.168.2.124 ComputerA      1ABCDEFG    00xxYYbbCCdd [Unknown]
```

I want to be able to replace the [Unknown] text with a Username I have retrieved from a different source. Can I update just the User column on this line in Devices.csv using powershell and keep the rest of the CSV file intact ?

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$csv = Import-CSV Devices.csv
$csv | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -eq '192.168.2.124'} | Select-Object -Last 1 | ForEach-Object {$_.User = $user}
$csv | Export-Csv Devices.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Shay, Exactly what I wanted, Thanks Brian

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$otheruser = '...'

Import-Csv Devides.csv | % {
  if ($_.User -eq '[Unknown]') { $_.User = $otheruser }
  $_
} | Export-Csv Divices_modified.csv -NoTypeInformation
```