# Prepend / append data to one column in csv in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm really liking what I have seen of Powershell. But I'm really confused by some things, as I have so much to learn. I've been reading everything on the site here, but I've not been able to figure this out. Hopefully this is simple. I have a csv like this:

```
Title,Name,Office,Phone
Boss,Bob,101,323.555-1212
Office-Manager-Level-2,Helen,202,5-1213
Time-Waster-Level-5,Nemo,105,5-1214
Widget-Maker,Zack,10,5-1215
Temp,Larry,102,5-1000
```

I have been trying to figure out an easy way to prepend & append data to the first column, "Title", that will take eventually become a static webpage with the user's information. I'm trying this so far:

```
$file = ("\\web\users.csv")
$urlbase="<a href`=`"file:///web/users/info/"
$urlend="_info.html`">"
$data = import-csv ($file) -header ("Title","Name","Office","Phone")
$data | select -Skip 1  | % { $_.Title -replace '$_.Title', "'$urlbase'$_.Title'$urlend'`">'$_.Title'</a>"} | Export-CSV -Path "links_output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

However - all that I'm matching or replacing it appears is the length of the string (??) of the first column of data. My output file is this:

```
"Length"
"4"
"23"
"19"
"12"
"4"
```

What I would desire as my output would be:

```
<a href="file:///web/users/info/Boss_info.html"Boss</a>"
<a href="file:///web/users/info/Office-Manager-Level-2_info.html">Office-Manager-Level-2</a>"
<a href="file:///web/users/info/Time-Waster-Level-5_info.html">Time-Waster-Level-5</a>"
<a href="file:///web/users/info/Widget-Maker_info.html">Widget-Maker</a>"
<a href="file:///web/users/info/Temp_info.html">Temp</a>"
```

Also, besides my basic issue, if I could use **set-content** I'd be happy because I'd really like this to be like a **sed -i** type of action/function, on the original file, but a new file with the same contents as the old with the updated first column will satisfy if I cannot set-content on the original.

This section of my script will become an html file later and because of issues with regex find and replacing with tags, I'm trying to add the html tags before I use **ConvertTo-Html**, because that is all working already. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying CSV content with Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470112/modifying-csv-content-with-powershell)

Comment: That and most all other examples that I've found always have a variable that is desired to change the data with. I need to prepend / append values to column. I need to be able to pass what is in the csv array, add to it, and export it and all other data back out.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you want to replace a field's value entirely or just modify it, the approach is the same. Prepending for instance would work like this: `... | % { $_.Name = 'prefix' + $_.Name }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
$file = ("\\web\users.csv")
$urlbase='<a href="file:///web/users/info/'
$urlend='_info.html">'

get-content $file | 
select -Skip 1 |
foreach {
"$Urlbase{0}$urlend" -f $_.split(',')[0]
}
```

The split(',') is an object method of [string] that will split the string at the commas, producing an array.  The trailing [0] takes the first element of that array, whic will be the Name.  That gets inserted at {0} in the format string between the other two variables by the format (-f) operator.

You can use the -replace operator, but you can't use PS variables in the replacement string.  You can include the literal text:

```
(get-content $file | select -Skip 1) -replace '^([^,]+)(.+)','<a href="file:///web/users/info/$1_info.html">$2'
```

Comment: That's great! OK -- but what about the rest of the data of the csv... I want to "replace" that column and save the whole thing out... can I continue to pipe it back into a csv with the other columns?

Comment: Are you wanting to save it back to the same file name, or a different file?

Comment: Whatever is easier. I was curious to learn if 'inline' find and replace with set-content was possible but exporting as a csv with all the other original data would be good.

Comment: I am just struggling so much with the syntax. Is the `-replace` function allowed to use the

Comment: Sorry - can I use a replace and output the rest of the data unchanged in the other columns or do I need to use the split method above and also pipe `[1] [2] [3]` columns out? Thanks

Comment: Posted an example.  (Note that should all be one line, not sure why it got split).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to form a regex match originally but failed miserably. Lots to learn. When I get some reputation I will vote this up!